# Why does "get-childItem -recurse | select-string foo" not result in an error if there are subdirectories?

Tags: powershell, pipeline

Trying to use `select-string` on a directory results in an error:

```
PS C:\> select-string pattern P:\ath\to\directory
select-string : The file P:\ath\to\directory cannot be read: Access to the path 'P:\ath\to\directory' is denied.
```

However, when I use `get-childItem -recurse`, the command finishes without problem:

```
PS C:\> get-childItem -recurse P:\ath\to | select-string pattern
```

This sursprises me because `get-childItem recurse` also passes directories down the pipeline. So, I'd have assumed that `select-string` raises the same error when it processes the first directory.

Since this is not the case, I wonder where or how the directory is filtered out in the pipeline.

Comment: it's because your 1st example failed to use parameter names ... and that forced PoSh to guess what went where. the pipeline version is getting things by the property name since that is how the cmdlet behaves while in a _pipeline_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR: object magic.

When `Get-Childitem` is run, it will return a collection of objects. This is passed to `Select-String`. The cmdlet's [source](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/src/Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Utility/commands/utility/MatchString.cs) is available on Github. There's a `ProcessRecord()` method that, well, processes input objects. It contains a few checks for object type and if those are directories. Like so,

```
if (_inputObject.BaseObject is FileInfo fileInfo)
...
if (expandedPathsMaybeDirectory && Directory.Exists(filename))
...
```

Thus, it doesn't matter that `Get-Child`'s collection contains both `DirectoryInfo` and `FileInfo` objects; the cmdlet is smart enough to figure out what it's trying to consume.

Comment: This explains why the error is not thrown when `select-string` is used together with `get-childItem`. Do you happen to know why `select-string` does not perform a similar check when executed as `select-string pattern P:\ath`?

Answer (score 1):

The `-Path` parameter of [`Select-String`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-string) expects paths to files:

> -Path
>
> Specifies the path to the files to search. Wildcards are permitted. The default location is the local directory.
>
> Specify files in the directory, such as log1.txt, *.doc, or *.*. If you specify only a directory, the command fails.

That's why you get an error, when you pass a path to a directory to the `-Path` parameter.

When you pipe objects to `Select-String`, they do not necessarily need a `Path` attribute that can be mapped to `-Path` of `Select-String`:

> You can pipe any object that has a **ToString** method to `Select-String`.

So you can also pipe raw strings to `Select-String`:

```
'test' | Select-String -Pattern 'test'
```

This line will return `test`.

[`Get-ChildItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem) returns objects of type `System.IO.FileInfo` or `System.IO.DirectoryInfo`. `Select-String` will use the `Path` attribute of `System.IO.FileInfo` to parse the content of the file and it will use the string representation of `System.IO.DirectoryInfo` to parse exactly this string representation (the path itsself). That's why you don't get errors in your pipeline.

```
New-Item -Name 'test' -Type Directory | Select-String -Pattern 'test'
```

This line will return the path to the just created directory `test`.